# Is there a way to fetch a GORM entity with hasOne child lazily?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a simple one-to-one relation between two Grails entitites like this:

```
class Parent {
    static hasOne = [child: Child]
}

class Child {
    Parent parent
}
```

The problem is that when loading the parent entity (e.g. using `def parent = Parent.first()`), the child is selected from the database simultaneously with a second query as can be seen in the hibernate debug log, although according to [the documentation](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/lazy.html) single-ended associations should be fetched lazily by default. Also using the `lazy: true` mapping configuration from the mentioned docs apparently doesn't change anything.

The situation is the same when using `static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]` in the child instead.

[This issue](https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/issues/136) (currently open) describes the same behavior.

So is there any way to stop the child association to be fetched?

Optimally, I imagine it should be either fetched using a single select with join or not selected at all (or upon first access of the child), preferrably controlled by a switch or using a `fetch join` in a HQL query.

Comment: "preferrably controlled by a switch or using a fetch join in a HQL query" - Why is it that you would prefer that?  That can be done, but is more work than other options, including one referenced below.

Comment: OK, `fetch: 'join'` really fetches them together, thanks. But it's only half the problem, why `fetch: 'lazy'` or `lazy: true` doesn't prevent it from fetching at all (which should be default)? I want to choose if the nested entity will be fetched or not depending on situation - whether I need that data or not. I wonder how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

> Optimally, I imagine it should be either fetched using a single select
> with join or not selected at all (or upon first access of the child),
> preferrably controlled by a switch or using a fetch join in a HQL
> query.

It can be made to be fetched with a single select.

The issue at https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/issues/136 links to the sample project at https://github.com/alanbino/gorm-hasone.  I forked that to https://github.com/jeffbrown/gorm-hasone and made changes.

The commit at https://github.com/jeffbrown/gorm-hasone/commit/32cb943cbc27deb5ebf164aa1461b3956285fe1d demonstrates how to get the data retrieved in a single select.  That commits configures the join...

```
static mapping = {
    table 'a_parent'
    id generator:'assigned'
    aChild fetch: 'join'
}
```

The subsequent commit at https://github.com/jeffbrown/gorm-hasone/commit/575ae2152767ded30686cb2e3daa70519f03c8ba isn't really related to the issue here, but eliminates a number of complexities that don't relate to the issue and eliminating those makes it easier to evaluate the code.  Ignore that if that is a distraction.